# The data types nvarchar and nvarchar are incompatible in the subtract operator

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, runtime-error, data-conversion, nvarchar

I know this was asked before. I did research of previous answers and couldn't find solution for my problem. What's most curious in my case is that exact same code works on test database but not on production though they are exactly the same.  Procedure itself is very long but I managed to isolate problematic part. I hope someone sees something I don't because I lost 2 days on this and still have no idea:

```
DECLARE luUpdateCursor CURSOR  FORWARD_ONLY STATIC READ_ONLY FOR
    SELECT Id, DisplayFormat, LookupName FROM #ProductResults WHERE Value IS NOT NULL AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(LookupName))) > 0

OPEN luUpdateCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM luUpdateCursor
INTO @Id, @DisplayFormat, @LookUpName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   IF @LocaleID = @SystemLocaleId
        BEGIN
            SET @strSql = '
                UPDATE PR
                    SET PR.Value = ' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@DisplayFormat,'[','lk.['),',' , '+ '','' + ')  + '          
            FROM
                #ProductResults PR 
            INNER JOIN
                tblk_' + RTRIM(@LookUpName) + ' lk WITH(NOLOCK) ON PR.Value = lk.Id 
            WHERE
                PR.Id = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@Id)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @strSql = '
            UPDATE PR
                SET PR.Value = COALESCE(' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@DisplayFormat,'[','lkl.['),',' , '+ '','' + ') + ',' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@DisplayFormat,'[','lk.['),',' , '+ 
'','' + ')  + ')            
            FROM
                #ProductResults PR 
            INNER JOIN
                tblk_' + RTRIM(@LookUpName) + ' lk WITH(NOLOCK) ON PR.Value = lk.Id 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                tblk_' + RTRIM(@LookUpName) + '_Locale lkl WITH(NOLOCK) ON PR.Value = lkl.fk_Id AND lkl.FK_Locale = ' + CAST(@LocaleID AS NVARCHAR(20)) + ' 
            WHERE
                PR.Id = ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR,@Id)
    END 
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @strSql;
    FETCH NEXT FROM luUpdateCursor
    INTO @Id, @DisplayFormat, @LookUpName
END
CLOSE luUpdateCursor
DEALLOCATE luUpdateCursor;
```

Table #ProductREsults has Id INT, and DisplayFormat and LookupNAme are both NVarchar. There is also one very similar query in procedure, actually same but on different table and that one works, so this bothers me so much.
Sorry if question is stupid.

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: Hello Biljana, you should better convert or cast string data types to int explicitely for mathematical operations

Comment: Please be aware that concatinating your @strSql as mentioned above will produce NULL as a result if one of your variables returns null. Either check them with ISNULL or use the CONCAT function (if you're using SQL Server 2012 or up - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

Comment: Sample value for `@DisplayFormat`

Comment: Also, try to avoid casting to NVARCHAR without specifying length. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length

Comment: It's complaining about a subtract operator, but there's no `-` in the code that you're showing. This suggests that it's lurking in the *data* that you're pulling through that cursor, so of course we can't help you find it. This could also explain why it works differently on different databases (with different data)

Comment: You don't seem to be using quotes around your variables in your end result. I can imagine how that could produce all sorts of problems. Instead of executing your result, print it out. It'll make a lot of things clear.

Comment: Wow, thanks everyone for fast answers! Actually, they all helped me to find the problem, especially JaydipJ and Daminen_The_unbeliever. When I listed values for @DisplayFormat, I found one that contains character "-" which of course, made a problem. Also, I specified length for nvarchar. thanks a lot!

Comment: In the future, when you build dynamic SQL like this, it really helps debugging if you print out the whole SQL before executing it - you'd see the problem immediately :)

Answer (score 0):

This error "The data types nvarchar(max) and nvarchar(max) are incompatible in the subtract operator." throws when you substract two variables or columns with data type as nvarchar.
Look for your other queries where you execute substruct operator or where it may be happend implicity.